# Ajax post data to external URL don't receive callback javascript jquery

Tags: javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("img").click(function()
        {
        $.post("https://.co.za/payweb3/initiate.trans",
            {
              PAYGATE_ID: "1029612100016",
              REFERENCE: "Basket_ACDDDDA1-816E-48D7-A9DB-64ECAC97C76",
              AMOUNT: "33900",
              CURRENCY: "ZAR",
              RETURN_URL: "https://www./checkout.asp",
              TRANSACTION_DATE: "2019-10-21 9:17:9",
              LOCALE: "en-za",
              COUNTRY: "ZAF",
              EMAIL: "dave@.co.za",
              NOTIFY_URL: "https://www./thanks.asp",
              CHECKSUM: "6251a4edec03bfcc86ad88112b10637d"
            },
            //Callback
            function(data) {
            alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
            //document.form1.submit();
            });
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I perform an ajax post to the external URL but don't receive the HTTP post reply. I have never had to do this before so I am a bit lost.

I adapted function from W3schools but bit in the dark...
This is the expected postback data from URL, I don't receive it. Please help.

`PAYGATE_ID=1029612100016&PAY_REQUEST_ID=C7701B85-F479-DBB1-73BE-B1D57F17EAE0&REFERENCE=Basket_ACDDDDA1-816E-48D7-A9DB-64ECAC97C76&CHECKSUM=40c4daefb5e7d1eef6fa6a085789b89c`

The callback doesn't work, not sure what I'm doing here?

Comment: are you getting any error in `developer console` ?

Comment: Check "response" in network tab in developer tools. There should be adress you POST and data that came back or at least error status.

Comment: Seriously, why do you share all that sensitive data here?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("img").click(function()
        {
        $.post("https://my.paymentgateway.com/some/endpoint",
            {
              PAYGATE_ID: "123456",
              REFERENCE: "BASKET_REF_123",
              AMOUNT: "33900",
              CURRENCY: "ZAR",
              RETURN_URL: "https://www.my.shop.com/checkout.asp",
              TRANSACTION_DATE: "2019-10-21 9:17:9",
              LOCALE: "en-za",
              COUNTRY: "ZAF",
              EMAIL: "dave@my.show.com",
              NOTIFY_URL: "https://www.my.shop.com/thanks.asp",
              CHECKSUM: "6251a4edec03bfcc86ad88112b10637d"
            }).done((data)=> {
                  // Success handling
            }).fail((xhr, status, error) => {
               // Error handling
            });
        });
});
```

Try to use the done() and fail() handlers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors in your snippet:

1. You have no `img` in your HTML, so it cannot be clicked. I changed it to a button in my snippet.
2. You seem to have **CORS** problems - that means the server thinks you are not allowed to request the resource you try to get. I put `http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` before your URL. Keep in mind that it's only a test solution, not for production. You either have to get the provider to set the correct headers (so accept your request), or you need to create a solution that goes around this problem. (So if you remove the URL part I put there, the snippet won't work.)
3. Something is not right with your request data, as it returns a **ERROR=DATA_CHK** message - this is not conventional, so I don't know what it means or implies.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://.co.za/initiate.trans", {
        PAYGATE_ID: "123456",
        REFERENCE: "Basket_ACDDDDA1-816E-48D7-A9DB-64ECAC97C76",
        AMOUNT: "33900",
        CURRENCY: "ZAR",
        RETURN_URL: "https://www./checkout.asp",
        TRANSACTION_DATE: "2019-10-21 9:17:9",
        LOCALE: "en-za",
        COUNTRY: "ZAF",
        EMAIL: "dave@.co.za",
        NOTIFY_URL: "https://www./thanks.asp",
        CHECKSUM: "6251a4edec03bfcc86ad88112b10637d"
      },
      function(data) {
        console.log('data:', data)
      })
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">CLICK HERE</button>
```

More on **CORS**:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

https://www.codecademy.com/articles/what-is-cors

Comment: I didn't include the img, sorry new to this :( I will review the error it is sending back. Thank you

Comment: Thank you. Question, how do I access individual string variables returned by the postback? ie PAY_REQUEST_ID from:PAYGATE_ID=1029612100016&PAY_REQUEST_ID=C7701B85-F479-DBB1-73BE-B1D57F17EAE0...

Comment: If you receive the correct string (what you expect), but it's in the format above, you can do (at least) two things: parse this string to an **Object** (by **&** and **=**), or it looks almost a **GET** query string - you might try treating it as such and parse it that way